# CSS Selector-How to locate Parent Element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

Is there any way to locate parent element in CSS Selector?
i am using below code but i am not getting the parent element.

```
WebElement we=dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='gf-BIG']:parent"));
```

I know there is a way in XPath but please let me know that how we can locate parent in CSS Selector.

Comment: css does not give you the flexibility of walking down the nodes as xpath does

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Referring to the [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) topic, there is *no parent selector in CSS*. Leave the "getting the parent" part to the XPath:

```
WebElement we = dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='gf-BIG']"));
WebElement parent = we.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
```

Answer (score 1):

If it would help here is example how get it by xpath

```
WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gf-BIG']/parent::parentElementTag"));
```

*parentElementTag - could be div/span/tr - depends on your case*

Answer (score 1):

If the parent is say div, you could try something like below

```
div div[id='gf-BIG']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way(like using :parent OR :preceding), we can use CSS Selector for finding the parent element.

1. CSS Provides support for siblings
2. CSS Provides support for childs
3. CSS Provides support for element which has specific child element with :has() function. This may help at some extent for finding parent. (Reference: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector))

However, we can not find Parent element directly using CSS.

Needless to say - CSS selector is best way to find elements as far as performance matters.

Comment: have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector hope that helps